# PHP char encoding to UTF-8 from various sources

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Hey, guys. I work for http://pastebin.com and we have a little issue with the new API and char encoding.

On the site itself we run a meta tag which specifies that everything on the site, including the forms, are utf-8. Because of this all chars get stored in the right way, without having to modify any char types.

With the API however, people can send data from all kinds of different sources & forms, and therefor has to get checked and possibly changed, before storing it.

Chars that are giving a problem are for example:

고객님이 티빙

Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn
♥♥♥♥♥

идите в *оопу, он лучший)

What would be a good way to approach this data input to the API to make sure all chars get stored in a valid UTF-8 format, which will work on our site.

Comment: Check out this possible duplicate: [What is the best way to handle uploaded text files of different encodings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127763/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-uploaded-text-files-of-different-encodings) it's about a slightly different scenario but the basic premise is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your client is sending utf8 data and headers correctly: Sounds like you're doing a utf8_encode() on already-encoded utf8 data.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate: [What is the best way to handle uploaded text files of different encodings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127763/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-uploaded-text-files-of-different-encodings)

In a nutshell, the only reliable way is having the client specify what encoding they are using. Automatic encoding detection is imperfect and tends to be unreliable.

You could for example specify that incoming data needs an encoding specified if it's not UTF-8.

Comment: +1 Yep, the best solution is to **force** the client to specify the character encoding. Or in terms of *The Zen of Python*: “Explicit is better than implicit.”

Comment: Even if client specifies encoding, if you encode it *again*, you have problems.

Comment: @servermanfail sure, but I don't think that's the case here. He seems to be asking more about general practices and how to deal with different encodings